# How to display extra fields for user

Tags: users, profiles

I have searched for a solution to this for days without any luck.

I have added a new field to my user profile record with the plugin: [Profile Extra Fields](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/profile-extra-fields/).

How do I get this field value display on my html front page?

Comment: Do you code and/or do you have access to the source code for the theme you're using? I can see a coder-friendly way to do it. But if you don't code and hope for a way using plugins or purely the WordPress-backend, then I think I would try and look for another plugin. I looked through it's documentation ( https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dS8WUgdJOa4O5Ft48oe3z4iGTyN0cXC-SBBDoeHbChk/edit#heading=h.h5gkjdzeitg5 ), and I would look at the Shortcode-section if I was you. Try inserting this on a page: `[prflxtrflds_user_data]`

Comment: Thanks for the effort @zeth.I have removed all the installed plugins because they dont seem to solve my problem, created the extra profile fields by coding.Kindly help me look at my plugin code here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/techng/dgeq6kj3/). How can I display these fields on my page.